# Installing a PHP extension on Windows 10

Tags: php, windows, cakephp, pecl

I've been away from PHP for a while. Right now, I have a working CakePHP 3.x site running on IIS. Now, I need to install and use an extension (specifically a Couchbase extension, but I don't think my problem is Couchbase specific).

I've downloaded the DLL from PECL ([here, the 5.6 Thread Safe 32bit download, specifically](https://pecl.php.net/package/couchbase/2.3.4/windows))

I think that I have to put the files in that zip file somewhere, and then I have to make a change to php.ini under ExtensionList. But I'm not sure where to put the files specifically, or which DLLs to reference.

I tried putting them in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext\couchbase` and then I added `extension=couchbase/php_couchbase.dll` to php.ini, restarted IIS. Then, I wrote this simple CakePHP controller just to make sure that worked:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

class ProfilesController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $cluster = new CouchbaseCluster("couchbase://127.0.0.1");
        $bucket = $cluster->openBucket("sqltocb");

        $query = CouchbaseN1qlQuery::fromString("SELECT b.* FROM `sqltocb` b LIMIT 10;");
        $query->consistency(CouchbaseN1qlQuery::REQUEST_PLUS);
        $result = $bucket->query($query);
        echo json_encode($result->rows);
    }
}

?>
```

But I get an error `Error: Class 'App\Controller\CouchbaseCluster' not found`, which I assume to mean that I didn't install the extension correctly. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're not pointing to a (fully qualified) [**namespace**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php). Also according to their [**API docs**](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-php-client-2.3.4/namespaces/Couchbase.html) it's `\Couchbase\Cluster` and `\Couchbase\N1qlQuery`.

Comment: I added `namespace \Couchbase\Cluster;
use \Couchbase\N1qlQuery;` and now I get a different error: `Error: Class 'App\Controller\CouchbaseCluster' not found  `

Comment: Looks like the same error to me. And did you really add `namespace ...`, or is that a typo and you ment `use ...`? For starters you should just need to replace `CouchbaseCluster` with `\Couchbase\Cluster`, and `CouchbaseN1qlQuery` with `\Couchbase\N1qlQuery`.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, I used 'use'. I tried the above, still similar error: `Error: Class 'Couchbase\Cluster' not found `, maybe I'm doing something wrong with the ini/dll?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure that you can provide paths for extensions in the ini file, better try to put the file directly in the extension folder (as configured in `extension_dir`)... are you sure there aren't any startup errors? Check your PHP error logs. Also make sure that the PHP configuration that you're modifying is actually the one that the server uses.

Comment: Could you make sure you have couchbase extension loaded? Could you post output of these commands? `php -i | grep 'couchbase\|json'
php --modules | grep 'json\|couchbase'`

Comment: @KevinKyaw I'm on Windows, no grep, but the output of `php -i` doesn't contain any instances of "couchbase" (I assume that's what you're going for)

Comment: @ndm I tried copying the dlls everywhere, and removing the path from ini file, still no dice. The error logs (PHP56_errors.log) are only showing the errors I've already listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My system version

```
PS> [Environment]::OSVersion

Platform ServicePack Version      VersionString
-------- ----------- -------      -------------
 Win32NT             10.0.14393.0 Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0
```

Download and extract PHP interpreter and the Couchbase extension:

```
PS> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.6.31-Win32-VC11-x86.zip" -OutFile "php-5.6.31-Win32-VC11-x86.zip"
PS> Expand-Archive "php-5.6.31-Win32-VC11-x86.zip" -DestinationPath "C:\php"
PS> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://packages.couchbase.com/clients/php/php_couchbase-2.3.4-5.6-zts-vc11-x86.zip" -OutFile "php_couchbase-2.3.4-5.6-zts-vc11-x86.zip"
PS> Expand-Archive "php_couchbase-2.3.4-5.6-zts-vc11-x86.zip" -DestinationPath "C:\php\ext"
```

Copy `libcouchbase.dll` to the place where your SAPI lives (in our case SAPI is PHP CLI, so we copy it into the same directory, where `php.exe` located):

```
PS> copy "C:\php\ext\libcouchbase.dll" "C:\php\libcouchbase.dll"
```

Update configuration:

```
PS> copy "C:\php\php.ini-development" "C:\php\php.ini"
PS> "extension=php_couchbase.dll" | Add-Content "C:\php\php.ini"
```

Lets check setup:

```
PS> C:\php\php.exe -i 2>$null | findstr -i couchbase
couchbase
couchbase support => enabled
libcouchbase runtime version => 2.7.6 (git: e15b267765913f110fd1bbf65749c54b56875ebf)
libcouchbase headers version => 2.7.6 (git: e15b267765913f110fd1bbf65749c54b56875ebf)
igbinary transcoder => disabled (install pecl/igbinary and rebuild pecl/couchbase)
couchbase.decoder.json_arrays => 0 => 0
couchbase.encoder.compression => off => off
couchbase.encoder.compression_factor => 0.0 => 0.0
couchbase.encoder.compression_threshold => 0 => 0
couchbase.encoder.format => json => json
couchbase.log_level => WARN => WARN
```

If you are using something different instead of `C:\php`, then make sure your extension directory match to place where PHP is looking for extensions, because this is is what it outputs by default (and `php.ini-development` does not override it):

```
PS> C:\php\php.exe  -i 2>$null | findstr -i extension_dir
extension_dir => C:\php\ext => C:\php\ext
```

All snippets executed in home directory using PowerShell, and `PS>` means its prompt.

Comment: I pretty much followed all these steps in the first place. The key difference is that you used `c:\php`, while I used `c:\program files\php\v5.6\'. In the externsion_dir I had to set it to an escaped string `"c:\\Program Files\\php\\v.5.6\\ext\\"` and then it worked okay.